# swift: passing by reference

Tags: swift, reference

Coming from JS, and trying to pass [JSON] by reference in swift, which is not possible, so I'm trying to wrap it in the object, and made a simple example using a primitive, which still not working, how can i wrap member a, so that changes in referenced object a affect b ? Thanks

```
class ExampleA {
    var a = 0
    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }
}
class ExampleB {
    var a = 0
    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }
    func process(inout p: ExampleA) {
        self.a = p.a
        print(p.a)
    }
}

var a = ExampleA(a: 15)
var b = ExampleB(a: 10)

b.process(&a)

print(b.a)  // "15\n"
a.a = 25    // this does nothing to b????
print(b.a)  // "15\n"
```

Comment: Why would it affect `b`?  You don't call `process` after changing `a.a`.

Comment: You should setup some explicit delegate structure to cause the values to change based on others. They should not just implicitly, "magically" change their values.

Comment: there is no way to reference something like in JS to reflect changes instantly as values changed in referenced object?

Comment: luk2302 could you give an example?

Comment: @andreg I gave an answer, but I don't recommend you use it. Swift has value types intentionally. It tries to keep you from going down the road of spaghetti code, side effects and unintentional data sharing. As much as I love JS, it accommodates that sort of bad design very readily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example fails because `a` is an `Int`, which is a value type.

When you do the assignment `self.a = p.a`, you're making a copy of the Int.

To achieve the reference semantics you want, you have to hold reference the `ExampleA` that's storing the value type. I think you got confused because of your variable naming, confusing the `a : Int` member of `ExampleA` with instances of `ExampleA` named `a`.

Here's a fix I put together. It gives `ExampleB` a computed property that transparently accesses the `data` in `ExampleA`.

```
class ExampleA {
    var data = 0
    init(data: Int) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class ExampleB {
    var a : ExampleA

    var data : Int {
        get {
            return a.data
        }
        set {
            a.data = newValue
        }
    }

    init(data: Int) {
        self.a = ExampleA(data: data)
    }

    func process(a: ExampleA) {
        self.a = a
        print(a.data)
    }
}

var a = ExampleA(data: 15)
var b = ExampleB(data: 10)

b.process(a: a)

print(b.data)  // "15\n"
a.data = 25 
print(b.data)  // "25\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple delegation works without any real need for `inout` or reference semantics:

```
class ExampleA {
    var a = 0
    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }
}
class ExampleB {
    var aObject: ExampleA
    init(a: ExampleA) {
        self.aObject = a
    }

    func a() -> Int {
        return aObject.a
    }
}

var a = ExampleA(a: 15)
var b = ExampleB(a: a)


print(b.a())
a.a = 25
print(b.a())
```